# Get a list of sbs 2011 backups that contain full backup as opposed to incremntal backup

Tags: windows-server-backup

I am using the SBS 2011 Windows Backup to backup to 8 USB drives that are rotated weekly.
It appears that the backup utility creates a full backup when a new drive is utilized for the first time or every 14 days.
I would like to get a list of the drive id and date each time a full backup was created, but not when a incremental backup is created.
Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Thanks
Howard